# SpriteKit Game Logic

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a level-based game using two SKSpriteNodes as buttons to go to either the next or previous level which will cause the GameViewController to present a new scene. I made the SKScene to have a property that directly references the gameviewController in order to call a present new scene function, but from what I understand, that breaks the MVC model. Is this bad? What is an alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard alternative for iOS programming is a pattern called delegation. First, you create a protocol to abstract away the implementation of switching levels.

```
protocol LevelSelector: class {
    func didSelectNextLevel(from scene: SKScene)
    func didSelectPreviousLevel(from scene: SKScene)
}
```

The `GameViewController` implements this protocol to change to the scene for the appropriate level. Each scene implementing a level has:

```
weak var levelSelector: LevelSelector?
```

The `GameViewController` then sets itself as the `levelSelector` for each level scene:

```
scene.levelSelector = self
```

When the user taps on the `SKNode`s representing the next and previous level buttons, call the appropriate method:

```
levelSelector?.didSelectNextLevel(from: self)

//OR

levelSelector?.didSelectPreviousLevel(from: self)
```